# How to Close the "Music + Videos" Process on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

When I call the MediaPlayer.Stop() method The Music Player stopped, but I still can see the last song's information in the volume panel like this: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92PYF.jpg)

What can I do if I want to hide or close it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to use the BackgroundAudioPlayer class and BackgroundAudioPlayer.Track property from the Micrsoft.Phone.BackgroundAudio namespace. You can clear the que of tracks being played by the background audio player and shown on the Universal Volume Control (UVC) by setting AudioTrack to Null. The reason you're still able to see the last played song is because it's still in the AudioTrack que. Also, look into MediaHistory and MediaHistoryItem class. These classes allow you access to the Music Hub for the phone. I got all my information from the MSDN documentation and an example of a BackgroundMediaPlayer, so follow these links for more information:

[BackgroundAudio Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[BackgroundAudioPlayer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.backgroundaudioplayer.track%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[BackgroundAudioPlayer Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. But how to convert a [Song](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Song%29;k%28Song%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-WindowsPhone) instance to a [AudioTrack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.audiotrack(v=vs.105).aspx) instance? because I get the MP3 files from the [MediaLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx), it return the result as SongCollection. Thank you!